# PHP PDO error on execution with execute function

Tags: php, sql, pdo

I am using PHP PDO connection and the following query execution is not giving me results. Instead, it throws the following error:

> Fatal error: Call to a member function fetchAll() on a non-object

```
$req = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM TableName WHERE id=:id", array(PDO::ATTR_CURSOR => PDO::CURSOR_FWDONLY));
//$req->bindParam(':id',$id,PDO::PARAM_STR);
$res = $req->execute(array(':id'=>$id));
var_dump($res); // returns boolean true
var_dump($res->fetchAll());   // giving error -- calling fetchAll() member function on non-object
```

Any suggestions on this.

Comment: Use `$req->fetchAll()`. [`PDOStatement::execute()`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php) always returns a `boolean`.

Comment: RTM - [PDOStatement::execute](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php) _"Returns TRUE on success or FALSE on failure"_

Comment: @Phylogenesis, @Magnus Eriksson, thanks for your inputs. Instead of using the variable `$res`, I used `fetchAll() on $req` itself and I got the results.